# Martingale Difference implies white noise

Tags: time-series, martingale

A white noise sequence needs to have 0 mean, uncorrelated $\epsilon_t$ and $\epsilon_{t+k}$ and constant variance. A martingale difference sequence has 0 mean and uncorrelated $\epsilon_t$ and $\epsilon_{t+k}$.

Is it possible to show that all Martingale Difference Sequences have constant variance? In general, is it true that all martingale difference sequences are white noise?

Comment: **Hint**: Of course not. Can you construct a counterexample? (Try modifying the construction of a random walk in a way that violates the very condition you've stated in your question.)

Comment: Following @cardinal 's hint: Consider the random walk defined by $y_t = \epsilon_1 + ... + \epsilon_{t}$ where $\epsilon_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0, t)$ are independent. Then $\{\epsilon_t\}$ is a martingale difference sequence that does not have constant variance.